# Timing Queries in Redis-Cli?

Tags: redis

This seems like it ought to be trivial, but I want to run a query through redis-cli, and then just get back how long it took on the server, along with the results. This is just for debugging purposes, to factor out problems with my client library or latency. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: maybe have a look at http://redis.io/commands/slowlog

Comment: @r043v I don't wanna see my slowest queries. I just wanna see timing on a specific query (it could be relatively fast).

Comment: i know but there is no real way to do this, the client must see it himself, maybe use redis-benchmark to check your commands time https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/db862e8ef0a7f857beb8b7db1a5c70093832033b/src/redis-benchmark.c

Comment: try this >> $ time redis-cli set foo bar

Comment: also set in redis.conf the verbose to debug can show you time start and end :

[20556] 09 Aug 16:07:42.568 - Accepted 127.0.0.1:52110
[20556] 09 Aug 16:07:42.569 - Client closed connection

Comment: using redis time command before and after your test command in a multi context work fine, php exemple >  http://pastebin.com/XyapBL7q lua could be sweet to made a generic speed test function

Answer (score 25):

You can do this by wrapping the redis command you're investigating in a `MULTI/EXEC` block, where the `TIME` command is used right *before* and right *after* your command. For example:

Using the node library:

```
var multi = redis.multi();
multi.time(); // start time
multi.sunionstore(['fast_food_joints', 'pizza_hut', 'taco_bell']); // this is the command I'm investigating
multi.time(); // end time
multi.exec(function(err, responses){
    var response = responses[1]; // the response i care about
    var start = (parseInt(responses[0][0]) * 1000) + (parseInt(responses[0][1]) / 1000);
    var end   = (parseInt(responses[2][0]) * 1000) + (parseInt(responses[2][1]) / 1000);            
    var execution_time = end - start; // in milliseconds
});
```

Or... using the command line (which is what you asked for in your question):

```
192.168.1.1:6379> MULTI
OK
192.168.1.1:6379> TIME
QUEUED
192.168.1.1:6379> SUNIONSTORE fast_food_joints pizza_hut taco_bell
QUEUED
192.168.1.1:6379> TIME
QUEUED
192.168.1.1:6379> EXEC
1) 1) "1450818240"
   2) "666636"
2) (integer) 48886
3) 1) "1450818240"
   2) "666639"
```

And then do the math yourself. The above example took 3 microseconds.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the Slow Log to 0 (zero). Doing so will log every command.

The time you will see is in microseconds, and from the documentation this time means:

> The execution time does not include the I/O operations like talking
>   with the client, sending the reply and so forth, but just the time
>   needed to actually execute the command (this is the only stage of
>   command execution where the thread is blocked and can not serve other
>   requests in the meantime)

To factor in the network performance you might have to hack your client library, logging just before and after the communication with redis, leaving out any tranformation your library may do.