# PHP Predis timeout not working as expected

Tags: php, redis, predis

```
    $client = new \Predis\Client([
            'tcp://192.168.24.128:8001?slots=0-5460&persistent=1&timeout=0.05&read_write_timeout=0.05',
            'tcp://192.168.24.128:8002?slots=5461-10922&persistent=1&timeout=0.05&read_write_timeout=0.05',
            'tcp://192.168.24.128:8003?slots=10923-16383&persistent=1&timeout=0.05&read_write_timeout=0.05',

        ], ['cluster' => 'redis'
        ]);

$start = microtime(true)
$client->rpush( "oxReqQueue", "bla bla bla");
print_r(microtime(true) - $start) // gives me value in order of 200 to 500 milliseconds.
```

We have set a timeout of 50 milliseconds but calls take > 50 milliseconds. Checked this from timing calls using grafana and also using above code.
But if I set that value to something like 0.5 milliseconds, then all calls are timing out.
Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried *not* setting up timeouts and benchmarked your code ? Also, I believe you meant `0.5 seconds`.

Comment: It is 0.5 millisecond, i meant if i set it to a really low value, all calls are timing out, but if i set it to 1 ms and in cases where Redis becomes slow, i.e. CPU of redis hitting 100%, we see roundtrips taking 250 milliseconds whereas the timeout value was set to 1 ms.

Comment: Got your point. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34424594/152016, and check the timestamps at the `TIME` command output and check if your timeout is not being considered.

Comment: (If it's being observed, the php client or network are the reason for lag)

Comment: The lag is still fine, but the bigger problem is the timeouts not being honored. We're still fine if the call times out, instead of it taking let's say 200ms instead of the said 50ms for whatever reason, as that clogs up resources

Comment: Did you measure the redis command with `TIME` ? See the answer I linked to and try to do that please.

Comment: My point is that your measured time is redis + php client overhead, and the `timeout` option you pass to the redis server only considers redis overhead.

Comment: I get your point, but I tried a 1ms timeout and worst cases were still taking in the order of 200ms. Let redis take whatever time it's taking, but I don't want the application to suffer because of that and timeout after a value specified, which is my broader issue.